# How do I convert a string to a function name that doesn't currently exist? e.g Service.<Name>() where name would be the string

Tags: python, sqlite, soap, zeep

I am currently working on a project requiring the use of soap and I am using zeep to make the post request, but I require the capability of using a string value stored in a database (sqlite) to modify the Service call so it can be changed any time without having to edit the code as the database can be amended and new values added by user input so I cant use a dictionary to store function equivalents

database format: Name type String, WSDL type String
the service call: res = Service.Name() #where name is replaced by a selected name from the database

is this possible if so how would I go about doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the built-in [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr)

```
method = getattr(Service, 'name')
res = method()
```

Comment: Glad to help, another way you could have solved this is to create a dict of functions: https://repl.it/repls/FamousLightheartedPublisher